# Logging user statistics on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Ruby on Rails app running on Heroku. Is there an easy way to log simple data like unique visitors per day so that I can later on graph the number of unique visitors over time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a **Web Analytics Service**.

[Google Analytics](https://www.google.de/analytics/), [Chartbeat](http://chartbeat.com/), [Kissmetrics](http://www.kissmetrics.com/), [Mixpanel](https://mixpanel.com/) et al. provide services like registering how many unique users visited your site, and are independent from where you run your app.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of things would you like to track? What you describe can be realized quite easily with [Google Analytics](http://google.com/analytics).